# Distributed file system that lets to specify on which machine a file is stored

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, hdfs, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I am looking for a distributed file system that for some files would let me to specify on which machine(s) they are stored (during the creation time). Ideally with a Java API. Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDFS has a block placement policy which can be plugged with a new policy. More details [here](http://hadoopblog.blogspot.in/2009/09/hdfs-block-replica-placement-in-your.html).

Also, MapR implementation of Hadoop has a more robust control over data placement. More details [here](http://www.mapr.com/products/only-with-mapr/data-placement-control).